# Is Microsoft C++ Build Tools available as portable (without installation)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

We are currently using CUDA on windows which requires MS C++ Build tools installed. With every new version of the CUDA toolkit it happens that newer versions of Visual Studio are not supported. That's why we are using the MS build tools seperately so that the VS version doesn't matter.

Since its hard to guide our developers to install the right CUDA and MSVC version we have packaged it into NUGET packages so that the toolkit (especially NVCC) is in a defined version and location. Additionally we wanted to do this with MSVC but we couldn't find a good solution since the installer obviously does modifications on several places that we don't know.

Is there any good way to get the MSVC tools portable so that we can simply drop it into a folder and put the right pathes?

NVCC doesn't support GCC, otherwise I would have gone with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [PortableBuildTools](https://github.com/Data-Oriented-House/PortableBuildTools), You can download a standalone MSVC compiler, linker & other tools, as well as headers/libraries from Windows SDK, into a portable folder, without installing Visual Studio.
[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the hint.